# Bounty expired and not awarded to anyone

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I added a bounty on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593899/validationmessagerfor-and-addmodelerror-not-working) question. No one was able to answer the question correctly and also there was no answer with votes 2 or more. In such a case the bounty is not awarded to anyone and is not added in my account.

If I want answer of this question and add bounty again do I need to again spend a reputation?

Is this by design that in that case the reputation will simply vanish, can't the user reuse the same for adding bounty on that question later or on other question?

Comment: It's by design -- you pay for promoting the question (which is more likely to make people answer), but not a guaranteed answer to a question.

Comment: A bounty is not a 'guaranteed answer fee'; it is a marketing fee. You pay to have your question promoted. Part of the promotion is the potential to win that bounty, sure, but you as the bounty sponsor still got your promotion out of it.

Comment: Looks self-inflicted to me.  Read this: http://www.sscce.org/